# javascript calculation field comparison algorithm

Tags: javascript, validation, textfield, jquery-calculation

Good day,

I have 3 text fields for input.

```
TotalWeight
CustomUnitWeight
CustomsNumberOfUnit
```

There should be a validation to make sure TotalCustomWeight matches TotalWeight (neither higher nor lower).

I started playing around trying to construct a function for validating this no luck and looking for assistance

Scenario :

User input total weight of pkg at 30, then put number of custom unit at 2 and the weight at 10. On click the function calculate 2 * 10 = 20 and look at the total weight 30 and compare the total custom weight. In this case 20 does not equal to 30 therfore throw error message.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="TotalWeight" id="TotalWeight" />
<input type="text" name="customsNumberOfUnitsUSA" id="CustomsNumberOfUnits" />
<input type="text" name="CustomsUnitWeight" id="CustomsUnitWeight" onChange="ChkWeight();" />
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function(ChkWeight){
    $('#CustomsUnitWeight').click(function() {
        var TotalWeight = document.getElementById('TotalWeight'); 
        var CustomUnitWeight = document.getElementById('CustomsUnitWeight'); 
        var CustomsNumberOfUnit = document.getElementById('CustomsNumberOfUnits');

        var TotalCustomWeight = CustomUnitWeight * CustomsNumberOfUnit;

        if (TotalWeight != TotalCustomWeight) {
            error message "pkg weight does not match total custom weight"
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: looking for assistance in how to make the validation work by clculating and comparing 2 values, if no match throw error

Comment: One obvious problem with your code is that you're getting two input elements and trying to multiply them together, instead of getting the value of said inputs. 
Try document.getElementById('TotalWeight').value; and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well everything else is fine in your code just needs to put **.value** to get value from your input fields and converting string (simple text) to Float type and then calculate and show alert like

```
 <body>
    <input type="text" name="TotalWeight" id="TotalWeight" />
    <input type="text" name="customsNumberOfUnits" id="CustomsNumberOfUnits"/>
    <input type="text" name="CustomsUnitWeight" id="CustomsUnitWeight"  onblur="CheckWeight()" />
    //I have changed the event as onblur and calling CheckWeight() function defined in javascript below.
 </body>


 <script type="text/javascrit">
  function CheckWeight()
  {
      var TotalWeight = document.getElementById('TotalWeight').value; 
      var CustomUnitWeight = document.getElementById('CustomsUnitWeight').value; 
      var CustomsNumberOfUnit = document.getElementById('CustomsNumberOfUnits').value;

      //parsing text value to Float type for multipication
      var TotalCustomWeight = parseFloat(CustomUnitWeight) * parseFloat(CustomsNumberOfUnit);

      if (TotalWeight != TotalCustomWeight)
      {
           alert("pkg weight does not match total custom weight");
      }
   }
 </script
```

and Off course you must need to validate for value to be number before calculation. This works perfect.

Comment: Im trying to figured it out using fiddle..no luck

Comment: what problem you are facing? May i see your fiddle?

Comment: do you have a live demo? im still struggling sorry

Comment: Your updated fiddle is not not found 404 error and what error you are getting?

Comment: Well I don't know why JSfiddle is not working but it works like charm when i run it my computer

Comment: You are absolutely right, I stopped working in fiddle to construct javascript function and transferred into my project and it worked..lesson learned fiddle not a good workbench it seem? Thank You answer approved